# Jquery live return false issue

Tags: jquery

issue jquery return false not working exactly.

```
$("input").live("mouseup",function()
{
return false
});

// Outside click action
$(document).mouseup(function()
{
$("input").hide();
});
```

Demo link

http://demos.9lessons.info/table_edit/TableEdit.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [`stopImmediatePropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/)

```
$("input").live("mouseup", function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

// Outside click action
$(document).mouseup(function() {
    $("input").hide();
});
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/qxRzC/).**

Comment: Hi Mark, Need help $("#div").html("test") inside jquery .live()

Comment: @Srinivas Tamada, could you update the jsfiddle to describe your issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input").live("mouseup",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Add your HTML to the question and define what exactly isn't working.

Comment: Works fine for me in IE and Chrome?

Comment: I want to run this script with .live()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$("input").live("mouseup",function(event)
{
    return false;
});
});
```